# No data available in table - datatables jquery issue

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a [jquery-datatables](/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) that I am populating from a method in C#.

The C# method returns some json which I have validated.  However my columns never get populated and instead I get a message that says `No data available in table.`

I'm completely stuck so hoping someone can help!

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: pageUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json",
            dataSrc: function (data) {
                console.log(data.d);
                return $.parseJSON(data.d);
            }
        },
        "pageLength": 50,
        fixedHeader: true,
        responsive: true,
        "columns": [
            {
                "data": "key",
                "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    if (type === 'display') {
                        data = '<a href="/software/details.aspx?id=' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
                    }

                    return data;
                } },
            { "data": "summary" },
            { "data": "created" },
            { "data": "updated" },
            { "data": "Status" },
            { "data": "priority" },
            { "data": "reporter" },
            { "data": "assignee" }
        ],
        autoWidth: false,
        "columnDefs": [
            { "width": "50%", "targets": 0 },
            { "width": "5%", "targets": 1 },
            { "width": "5%", "targets": 2 },
            { "width": "5%", "targets": 3 },
            { "width": "5%", "targets": 4 },
            { "width": "5%", "targets": 5 }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']],
        "success": fnsuccesscallback,
        "error": fnerrorcallback
    });

    function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
        alert(data.d);

    }

    function fnerrorcallback(result) {
        alert(result.statusText);
    }
```

And this is the data in the console.log output:

```
{"summary":"External Change Request Form: tester - 19/1/2021","created":"2021-01-19T15:32:02+00:00","updated":"2021-06-03T08:59:17+01:00","status":"To Do","key":"ITS-4711","assignee":"Bob","priority":"Low","reporter":"Dave"}
```

Comment: Looks like `data.d` is already a javascript object, not a JSON string, especially with `dataType:'json'` - try changing `return $.parseJSON(data.d);` to just `return data.d`

Comment: @freedomn-m that sorted it thank you! If you want to put that as an answer I can mark it as correct? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this part:

```
        dataType: "json",
        dataSrc: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d);
            return $.parseJSON(data.d);
        }
```

in `dataSrc` callback, `data` will already be a javascript object, not a JSON string.  Calling `$.parseJSON(object)` will generate an error, which it looks like datatables is catching (and ignoring, which is bad practice).

Thus giving an unrelated error message that there's no data, rather than that the data processing failed.

Change `return $.parseJSON(data.d);` to just

```
return data.d;
```